# Buddhism Supernatural feats and abilities

Tags: doubt

Recently i experiencing the psychic abilities, telepathy and seeing other dimension sentiment when i having this so call 3rd eye syndrome (All of it)
https://www.holycitysinner.com/2020/01/22/signs-your-third-eye-is-starting-to-see/

My psychic ability became more accurate and it's like Deja Vu then things really happened after 1-2 months. It's applicable to the stock market prices speculation price, date and how exactly it is speculated predicted 100% by mostly instinct. Sometimes when i am fully focused then i feel reading other people's mind and i will be winning throughout the night like a poker game, it's up to 90% accuracy. I am just a beginner poker player and winning all the senior players. I dont gamble much also. I felt so scared.

I used to be a Buddhism and Shaolin Kung Fu practitioner. I used to meditate in a martial arts way where there is a study that this can unlock the 7 chakra. The more I practice, the more I sense this ability. Sometime If i fully focus especially during critical time, i can think much faster, accurate even i sense future things.

I visited some doctors and my Buddhism senior. Some said use it for good, some said stop meditating.

My Buddhism senior commented that if it is so happening then it's devil abilities because I ' m really far far away from enlightenment requirement. Out of the 10 good deeds. I guess I only achieved 4 good merits, the rest just so so.

Question: Does it happen to someone just a 5-6 years Buddhism or junior practitioner ? Why such a things happening according to Buddhism? I just want to be a normal people and i dont require such abilities at the moment because my "good deed" is not good enough, perhaps i will use this for gambling or stock market or into devil's direction.

[https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miracles_of_Gautama_Buddha#:~:text=Psychic%20Abilities,-See%20also%3A%20Abhijñā&text=Following%20his%20enlightenment%2C%20the%20Buddha,and%20making%20copies%20of%20himself](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miracles_of_Gautama_Buddha#:%7E:text=Psychic%20Abilities,-See%20also%3A%20Abhij%C3%B1%C4%81&text=Following%20his%20enlightenment%2C%20the%20Buddha,and%20making%20copies%20of%20himself)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110161/discussion-on-question-by-anonymous-guy-buddhism-supernatural-feats-and-abilitie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Psychic powers are not necessary to end suffering:

> [DN24:1.4.13](https://suttacentral.net/dn24/en/sujato#dn24:1.4.13): What do you think, Sunakkhatta?
>
> [DN24:1.4.14](https://suttacentral.net/dn24/en/sujato#dn24:1.4.14): Whether or not there is a demonstration of psychic power, does my teaching lead someone who practices it to the goal of the complete ending of suffering?’
>
> [DN24:1.4.15](https://suttacentral.net/dn24/en/sujato#dn24:1.4.15): ‘It does, sir.’

Phenomena, including psychic powers, appear and disappear on their own without our grasping at them:

> [AN9.36:2.3](https://suttacentral.net/an9.36/en/sujato#an9.36:2.3): Take a mendicant who, quite secluded from sensual pleasures, secluded from unskillful qualities, enters and remains in the first absorption. They contemplate the phenomena there—included in form, feeling, perception, choices, and consciousness—as impermanent, as suffering, as diseased, as an abscess, as a dart, as misery, as an affliction, as alien, as falling apart, as empty, as not-self.

Focus on the Noble Eightfold Path instead of the phenomena. AN9.36 continues further, instructing us to experience and relinquish such phenomena with deeper practice--eventually, perception of those phenomena will fade with greater skill in immersion:

> [AN9.36:9.4](https://suttacentral.net/an9.36/en/sujato#an9.36:9.4): They turn their mind away from those things,
> ...
>
> [AN9.36:10.2](https://suttacentral.net/an9.36/en/sujato#an9.36:10.2): But the two dimensions that depend on these—the dimension of neither perception nor non-perception, and the cessation of perception and feeling—are properly explained by mendicants who are skilled in these attainments and skilled in emerging from them, after they’ve entered them and emerged from them.”

Answer (score 1):

Supernatural natural feats and abilities are not considered as a special part of the enlightenment. Even a person without having those powers would have enlightened instantly.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Oya Mist that psychic powers are not necessary for enlightenment. Additionally, the powers can become a major distraction. If you become interested in developing them, then you should wait until after you have reached enlightenment. The powers are a normal addition to an enlightened one. In fact, after awakening, the powers seem to appear as needed, on the spur of the moment.

Answer (score 0):

> some said stop meditating.

LOL of course authorities are normally afraid of people getting powerful. Don't mind about them, they're just afraid of losing control over the population and thus their privileges.

So; enjoy your new powers without fear; use them for good purposes. Try not to get addicted to gambling though. But earning a fortune will let you meditate better, without worrying about bills for example.

Being clairvoyant, maybe you could even talk to the bodhisattvas/buddhas like Avalokiteshvara or Amitabha and get teachings directly from them without having to rely on scriptures and authorities. That may help you reach enlightenment.