# Buddhism Supernatural feats and abilities (Part 2)

Tags: enlightenment

Subject refers, this is refer to URL below where question already closed
[Buddhism Supernatural feats and abilities](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/39586/buddhism-supernatural-feats-and-abilities)

This is some sharing with a question. Hope it will help some science development in finding the truth.

I only experienced 2 or 3 times out of it for the Supernatural feats that feel so real and close as explained for 3rd Eye or so called Quantum Entanglement in Pseudo Science.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KV7qC7qua1k
I have a long thought about how I did to have this during that time, I have a short temporary state of perfectionist or Buddhism 6 Paramita as below which I believe to have this super ability when a person achieves enlightenment. Or in other words, my mind just had fooled myself, fully focused and believed to have all the below but for a very short moment. For the poker game winning as mentioned in the previous link indeed I had donated all to the temple and I had this thinking while winning the game . I knew what Teacher taught me to use in gambling was wrong.

1. Dāna pāramitā (दान पारमिता): generosity, giving of oneself (in Chinese, Korean, and Japanese, 布施波羅蜜; in Tibetan, སྦྱིན་པ sbyin-pa)
2. Śīla pāramitā (शील पारमिता): virtue, morality, discipline, proper conduct (持戒波羅蜜; ཚུལ་ཁྲིམས tshul-khrims)
3. Kṣānti pāramitā (क्षांति पारमिता): patience, tolerance, forbearance, acceptance, endurance (忍辱波羅蜜; བཟོད་པ bzod-pa)
4. Vīrya pāramitā (वीर्य पारमिता): energy, diligence, vigor, effort (精進波羅蜜; བརྩོན་འགྲུས brtson-’grus)
5. Dhyāna pāramitā (ध्यान पारमिता): one-pointed concentration, contemplation (禪定波羅蜜, བསམ་གཏན bsam-gtan)
6. Prajñā pāramitā (प्रज्ञा पारमिता): wisdom, insight (般若波羅蜜; ཤེས་རབ shes-rab)
   Ques: Please someone validate the technique above can have some temporary Supernatural feats or Quantum Entanglement. If yes, then experience can be done during a Poker game for a person like Doctor Stuart Hameroff or whatever to simulate the scenario.

Well, I wish to go back to the human world and focus on the Noble Eightfold Path instead of the phenomena and let the Doctor handle this quantum world. If the information above is valid and the Doctor has faith, then he will find it.

Comment: Is this a blog post? Part 2 ???

Comment: The question appears to be, "Is it possible to have temporary Supernatural feats or Quantum Entanglement, which manifest as winning a poker game, especially when acting altruistically e.g. with the intention of giving winnings to the temple." I don't know  how (i.e. based on what) this question is meant to be answered, though.

Comment: I think the OP should edit the text or question to make this a valid one. ChrisW inferred a question from the text, but I think it'd better if the OP makes the question explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Poker is not pure gambling, but what gambling poker has is unskillful:

> [DN31:11.2](https://suttacentral.net/dn31/en/sujato#dn31:11.2): Victory breeds enmity. The loser mourns their money. There is immediate loss of wealth. A gambler’s word carries no weight in public assembly. Friends and colleagues treat them with contempt. And no-one wants to marry a gambler, for they think: ‘This individual is a gambler—they’re not able to support a partner.’

Beyond gambling, poker incorporates some measure of proficiency in "reading tells". Unfortunately, poker also involves deceit and strategies such as "all in" for betting, which is definitely unskillful for a Buddhist perspective.

> [MN117:29.1](https://suttacentral.net/mn117/en/sujato#mn117:29.1): And what is wrong livelihood? Deceit, flattery, hinting, and belittling, and using material possessions to pursue other material possessions.

Please reconsider your livelihood here, especially if you donate gains. Such gains can only be purified by the recipient, not the giver.

> [AN4.78:3.1](https://suttacentral.net/an4.78/en/sujato#an4.78:3.1): And how is a religious donation purified by the recipient, not the giver?  It’s when the giver is unethical, of bad character, but the recipient is ethical, of good character.

Practice the Noble Eightfold Path to benefit yourself before you seek to benefit others.

> [AN4.95:2.2](https://suttacentral.net/an4.95/en/sujato#an4.95:2.2): The person who practices to benefit neither themselves nor others is like this, I say.
>
> [AN4.95:3.1](https://suttacentral.net/an4.95/en/sujato#an4.95:3.1): The person who practices to benefit others, but not themselves, is better than that.
>
> [AN4.95:3.2](https://suttacentral.net/an4.95/en/sujato#an4.95:3.2): **The person who practices to benefit themselves, but not others, is better than both of those.**
>
> [AN4.95:3.3](https://suttacentral.net/an4.95/en/sujato#an4.95:3.3): But the person who practices to benefit both themselves and others is the foremost, best, chief, highest, and finest of the four.

In the above, "practice" is right practice according to the Noble Eightfold Path.